# How can this question about 'where to buy' be asked?

Tags: discussion

**I have read the [FAQs](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq)**

I know it is not allowed here. The thing is that the movie from this question [Boy sent to a mental asylum for teenagers where he falls in love](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8035/which-movie-is-this-no-actor-names-nor-character-names)  is really something hard to find, it's an unpopular TV movie and I think copies were never made.

Maybe as experts join this site, people who know how to get this kind of movie can tell how to find these.

What way is there to ask this question and be compatible with this site?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia entry for Mike McShane: "the film has never been released on video or DVD." You might be interested in this [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEoc92bXgMs) of it.  Director Chris Bould says he has a copy...

Answer (score 4):

No.

The simple fact is that it is essentially shopping advice that may be invalidated within a couple of hours and/or not be available at the same place as anyone else.

This is a perfect example why the *Too Localized* option exists when closing questions.

> Too Localized
>
> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Comment: the answer is "no", no what?

Comment: No, as in it is not allowed, nor is there any good way of having a "where can I buy X" be worded on this site.

Comment: ok ; i thought this site could cover that need